Deployment error for Importing/exporting DomUtil

Failed to compile
⨯ ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib/dom.js
Attempted import error: 'DomUtil' is not exported from 'leaflet' (imported as 'DomUtil').
This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
I'm just not sure what the problem is, I uninstalled and reinstalled react-leaflet and leaflet versions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
